# Anti-bumping granules

Tags: solutions

Anti-bumping granules are usually small stones. I presume that the principle of these granules ensuring smooth boiling, is that it blocks the upward motion of solution molecules.

Usually the stones have an irregular shape. I am wondering, if the anti-bumping granules are in regilar shapes, like a sphere, a cube, will there be some influences to the anti-bumping action of the granules?

Comment: The idea is to provide nucleation sites, so reasonable surface area and surface roughness are desirable. Small bubbles have higher internal pressures than large bubbles, other things equal, so Henry’s law works against the initial formation of bubbles. But tiny cavities in the surface of the “boiling stones” allow the bubbles to get initiated. You can see this in an old beer glass with beer in it: small bubbles stream up from such tiny cavities or rough spots in the glass.

Comment: Cross posted: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/781455/313612.

Comment: Nucleation (for boiling, effervescence,  or crystallization) can also be induced by *sound*, e.g., the "clicker" in sodium acetate hand-warmers... or for a fun geyser, put a cold, freshly opened bottle of soda in an ultrasonic bath or ultrasonic humidifier reservoir. Also, scratching a glass container with a glass rod produce both sound and imperfections to nucleate crystallization, https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Organic_Chemistry_Lab_Techniques_(Nichols)/03:_Crystallization/3.05:_Procedural_Generalities/3.5E:_Initiating_Crystallization .